# Mixing dynamic and static object keys in type or interface

Tags: typescript

I need something like this:

```
interface IMyInterface {
    Payload?: object;
    [key: string]: boolean | string | number | Date;
}
```

But the code above gives me the following error

> Property 'Payload' of type 'Object | undefined' is not assignable to string index type 'string | number | boolean | Date'.

Is there a way I can achieve the type I want through an `interface` or `type`?

Answer (score -1):

In your example: your second line in the definition of IMyInterface: `[key: string]: boolean | string | number | Date;` indicates, that all fields are of type `boolean | string | number | Date`

What you can define, by using union types, is:

```
type MyType =
    {[key : string]: boolean | string | number | Date} & { Payload?: object}
```